# Jquery Datatable Show no results match message if all rows are hidden

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am populating a html table from database and have applied client-side jquery based filtering of records. The records filter continuously as and when user types in. Based on the filtering condition, I tend to show or hide the rows as below.

```
gridRows.hide();
gridRows.show();
```

Everything seems to work fine. The issue I am facing is that I need to show a message like 'No results match your filter criteria' when all the rows are hidden. Currently, the code shows nothing. It just toggles all the rows. The below attributes like "emptyTable" or "zeroRecords" also doesn't work. Seems like they would work only if table would not have these rows at all. In my case, the rows are present but they are hidden. The reason I can't delete the rows is that I need to recover them once the filters are removed and everything is supposed to be client-side.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#testtable').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": [0, 1, 2],
                        "searchable": true,
                        "orderable": true
                    }
                ],
            "order": [[0, 'asc']],
            "bPaginate": false,
            "language": {
                "emptyTable": "<p>You have no data available.</p>",
                "zeroRecords": "No records match your filter criteria"                    
            }
        });
    });
```

The solutions I can currently think of would make things more complex. Any help would be appreciated!

The filtering mechanism I am using can be found below.
http://chris-spittles.co.uk/jquery-filter-table/

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most elegant solution, but if you are are not dynamically querying the database then the number of total records (hidden and shown) should be constant.

This would mean you could set a variable as a counter and increment it when you show or hide each record. If you put a hidden div with your message below the table, then you could just add an if statement to see if the number of hidden rows equals the total number of records and display the div accordingly.